# DynamicGridview items Dragdrop between Viewpager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, drag-and-drop, android-viewpager

I have used this [DynamicGridView](https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid/) and its really awesome, but unfortunately i am unable to understand to use it inside view pager fragments. Basically i have a view pager with 2 fragments and each fragment has some apps to which i want to drag drop to move to other fragments. (Just like we drag apps on samsung home screen). Hope I was able to explain my requirement.

I have also tried 
    [Android draggable viewpager](https://github.com/geftimov/android-draggable-viewpager) but its approach is different than my requirements.

Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to study [launcher](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_launcher/tree/master/src/com/) code of android. Also [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.0.1_r1/com/android/launcher3/Launcher.java#Launcher) link will help you. This is open source code and you need to study it. As per your requirement you want develop your own code in your application. hope it helps you.

Comment: you got me the right way, I want to make a launcher for android but i am confused how to drag app from apps screen to home screen.

Comment: did you read above link? because it helps you to how to implement drag and drop / moving view from one screen to other. Please go to through above link it really helps you. I could not explain whole code in launcher because it too vast. I have given only hint/idea to you

Comment: Thats great i just downloaded the project but it contains some errors in files can you help me regarding that?

Comment: Ya... definately. I guess, this error is default because that method used in launcher code can not used. just study code, you can not use this code as it is. You have to implement as your requirement and its very fun to study launcher code. It will gives us idea how they(android developer of launcher code) implement it. If any issue i will be their for your help always. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: its ok bro thanks a lot for your help.